# Swap Gender in SQL

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with my code?

**QUESTION**

**table:swap**

```
 +-------------+----------+
    | Column Name | Type     |
    +-------------+----------+
    | person_id   | int      |
    | name        | varchar  |
    | gender      | ENUM     |    |
    +-------------+----------+
```

id is the primary key for this table.
The gender column is ENUM value of type ('m', 'f'). Write an SQL query to swap all 'f' and 'm' values (i.e., change all 'f' values to 'm' and vice versa).

**MY CODE:** But the output doesn't swap gender.Please help.

```
with temp1 as
(select *, 
  (case when gender = 'm' then 'f' else 'm' end) as swapped_gender
 from swap)
 select person_id, name, swapped_gender as gender
 from temp1;
```

Comment: The output doesn't swap the gender. Please help.

Comment: Do you want to update the values back into the table or just display them with swapped genders?

Comment: The field name in your case statement does not match with the field name in your table.

Comment: @Shadow: sorry that is a typo, I meant gender

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I want to update the table

Answer (score 1):

> Write an SQL query to swap all 'f' and 'm' values (i.e., change all 'f' values to 'm' and vice versa).

Use numeric representation of ENUM value.

```sql
UPDATE swap 
SET gender = 3 - gender 
-- if empty values exists then uncomment
-- WHERE gender + 0 > 0 
;
```

Comment: works only if you have 2 gender in the enum and the first in not 'unused'

Comment: @BerndBuffen *works only if you have 2 gender in the enum and the first in not 'unused'* Shown ENUM definition (see the question) matches this conditions.